How to prevent "transform shape" from scaling the labels?
I don't want the labels to be scaled.

\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}


\newcommand\Triangle[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    % points A, B, C
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,#4/0/B}
    \tkzInterCC[R](A,#3)(B,#2)\tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black](A,...,C)
    
    % segments
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A,...,C)
    \tkzLabelSegment[sloped,anchor=270](B,C){\SI{#2}{\cm}}
    \tkzLabelSegment[sloped,anchor=270](C,A){\SI{#3}{\cm}}
    \tkzLabelSegment[sloped](A,B){\SI{#4}{\cm}}
    
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.5,thick](A,C,B)
\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}
\Triangle[scale=0.25,rotate=45,transform shape]{5}{12}{13}
\end{document}


\Triangle[scale=0.25,rotate=45, every node/.style={rotate=45}]{5}{12}{13} (but you don't scale the circle node either)

